# Query to retrieve values from different columns, based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I need to create a `QUERY` function to retrieve values from different columns, based on the following 2 criteria:

If the value in column A is "Company name changed", I need columns B and C.
And if the value in column A is "Email changed", I need to retrieve the corresponding values to that record from columns B, C, D and E.
All of the above in the same table.

**Please, excuse me for not sharing a dummy sheet, but I have corporate security restriction, which is not allowing me to make any sheet visible to anyone outside the company.**

Source tab:

```
+----------------------+------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
|           A          |   B  |      C      |             D            |              E             |
+----------------------+------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Status               | ID   | Company     | Email                    | Generic Email              |
+----------------------+------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Email changed        | 223A | ABC Capital | george@abccapital.com    | info@abccapital.com        |
+----------------------+------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| In progress          | 446g | DEF Finance | stephan@deffinance.co.uk | enquiries@deffinance.co.uk |
+----------------------+------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Company name changed | 233A | GHI Dealing | michael@ghidealing.ru    | contact@ghidealing.ru      |
+----------------------+------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Dissolved            | 334s | JKL Brokers | john@jklbrokers.au       | help@jklbrokers.au         |
+----------------------+------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Output tab:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| ID   | Company     | Email                 | Generic Email       |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| 223A | ABC Capital | george@abccapital.com | info@abccapital.com |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| 233A | GHI Dealing |                       |                     |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

What could be the possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={QUERY(A1:E, "select B, C, D, E 
               where A = 'Email changed'", 1);
  QUERY(A2:E, "select B, C, ' ', '  ' 
               where A = 'Company name changed'
               label ' ''', '  '''", 0)}
```

[image: 0]